# Three.js shading of complex model looks strange

Tags: three.js, webgl, shadow

We have a model created in Blender by subtracting an extruded SVG from a “flat” base using a boolean difference operator. Or in other words, we carved a picture into it. The model renders just fine in Blender, but loading it into our simple, three.js-based web viewer (using the json exporter for Blender), we get some really odd shadows on the surface, and depending on the scale, shiny vertexes.

Here's my light and camera:

```
    camera = window.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, $('main').width() / $('main').height(), 10, 10000);

    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    light.position.set(-30, 30, 100);
    light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    light.shadowCameraNear = 200;
```

Can anyone spot whether we did something wrong? And is that a Three-specific issue, or WebGL, or Blender, or our model?

[Output (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5t9i.png)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalomartins/45ARZ/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this technically counts as a solution, but — worked around the problem by dropping the JSON blender export, and using [P3D](https://github.com/D1plo1d/p3d) instead to load .stl directly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your fiddle, it seems that your vertexNormals are totally smoothed and thus shading is incorrect. 
See here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1258
Does this help?

Comment: Using FlatShading fixes the shading on the fiddle, unfortunately it doesn't with our real production models :-/

Can I prevent the vertexNormals from causing this? Is it something with my Blender model, or is it something about the json export?